# Anchoring bias (where does the anchoring come from ? (from transitive or intransitive verb)

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Anchoring bias describes the cognitive error you make when you tend to give more weight to information arriving early in a situation compared to information arriving later.

Does the 'anchoring' come from the intranstive 'anchor' or transitive 'anchor'? You know, the verb 'anchor' is used for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Anchoring bias*** is a composite noun, which includes the gerund "anchoring".

As a noun it cannot take a direct object so there seems to me no way on earth that it can be transitive.

And the question would seem to me entirely inconsequential anyway.

Comment: Thx. It not 'inconsequential' for me.

Comment: "why it is inconsequential".  Some verbs have transative forms that have different meanings to the intransitive.  This is not the case with  "anchor".  The intransitive form "I anchored in Spain"  means simply "I anchored (something, eg a boat) in Spain".  So it is *inconsequential* since there is no grammatical or semantic consequence of this fact.

Comment: @JamesK Good point. And in this case it is not being used as a verb anyway. So can a gerund be both transitive and intransitive? If you have the time you might like to consider that question in the context of one of your verbs where the two states reflect different meanings.

Comment: "Playing the piano makes Joe happy"   (transitive gerund)  compared with "Playing on the swings makes Joe happy" (intranstive)  Different meanings of the word "play" indicated by the direct object or location adjucnt.

Comment: @JamesK Is there some reason you do not subscribe much on EL&U? Seems to me you would contribute a great deal if you did.